# I get an Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Exception: A provisioning code must be provided Exception When I try to create a new Bucket, AWSSDK 3.1.6 C# AmazonS3

Tags: c#-4.0, amazon-s3

I am trying to connect amazon S3 + cleversafe with C# , I am using AWSSDK 3.1.0.0.
I want to create a new Bucket. 
I have a Provisioning Code = "my provisioning code" , host="my host", accesskey="my access key", secretKey="my secret key"
I tried the following code :

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, error) => { return true; };
BasicAWSCredentials basicCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("my access key", "mysecretkey");
AmazonS3Config configurationClient = new AmazonS3Config();
configurationClient.ForcePathStyle = true;
configurationClient.ServiceURL = "https://###.##.###.###";// my host is IPAdress
configurationClient.UseHttp = false;

try
{
    using (AmazonS3Client clientConnection = new AmazonS3Client(basicCredentials, configurationClient))
    {
        PutBucketRequest newBucket = new PutBucketRequest();
        newBucket.UseClientRegion = true;
        newBucket.BucketName = "NewBucketCleversafe";
        PutBucketResponse response = clientConnection.PutBucket(newBucket);
    }
}
catch (AmazonS3Exception exception)
{ 

}
```

but I get an "Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Exception: A provisioning code must be provided"
also I tried configurationClient.AuthenticationRegion = "my provisioning code"
Where Can I insert it("my provisioning code") in order to fix this Exception? Which Amazon S3 Class, Amazon S3 property should be modified?
Do you know How Can I fix it? any comment or idea  could be help. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a meeting with cleversafe he told me that I have to use BucketRegionName.so I used it but I get another Exception message "XML malformed exception " see more detail about it in https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/396(I do not get additional information about it from AWSSDK .net repository).
So conclusion Probably Cleversafe does not support createbucket using AWSSDK #C 3.1.6 3.5 .net